# Change math mode color

Tags: beamer, overleaf

I want to change the color of the mathematical mode of all my beamer, I have done it so far in an archaic way by defining the color by means of

```
\definecolor{melon}{rgb}{1.0, 0.72, 0.77}
```

and then modifying the command

```
\newcommand{\M}{\textcolor{melon}}
```

to make any equation do

```
\M{$a+b=c$}}
```

but now I would like all the math mode to have only one color, but I could not, I have seen several questions, but I still do not know if I'm doing it right, it is worth noting that the new color is 8c1919, thanks for your help.

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with? Defining the color? `\definecolor{oldbrick}{HTML}{8c1919}`? Or is it that you want it applied math mode without using a command like `\M`, or what? What have you tried?

Comment: `\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=oldbrick}`?

Comment: Please provide your `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`